# How do I get an image to fit 100% in width without stretching the image?

Tags: css, image, background

So I have a div with a background image. I would like the background image to always be 100% on the screen no matter what the screen size is. I would like the image to grow in proportion but crop the height. I don't want the image to stretch. What I have so far is:

```
#banner {
background:url(../images/blurry.jpg) no-repeat;
width:100%; 
height:520px;
background-size:100% 100%;

}
```

At the moment this is stretching the image to 100% and making the image look stretched.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CSS3 `background-size` property. Set it to `cover`. Like so:

`background-size: cover;`

Note that only IE9 and later supports this property value. IE8 will complain about an unsupported value. Chrome and Firefox supported `cover` since the past couple of years at least.

Comment: Thank you! What will happen if I use this in IE8?

Comment: IE8 will fall-back to whatever the last valid `background-size` property was. If you keep the `background-size: 100% 100%;` property (on the line above the `cover` one) then IE8 will fall-back to that.

Comment: So that means that the image will remain stretched like it has so far. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to give my answer an Up-vote and mark it as selected!